# Ayuda con script

Tags: javascript, script

Hola espero y me puedan ayudar, tengo el siguiente script y solamente el resultado3 me marca NaN

```html
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe Asegurado</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular();" name="importe" class="form-control m-b"></div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cuota Base (%)</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor2" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular();"  name="cuota" class="form-control m-b"></div>
  
<span id="result" type="text" name="prima"></span><br>
<span id="resultado3" type="text" name="iva"></span><br>
<span id="resulta2" type="text" name="total"></span>
```

```js
<script>
    function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*valor2/100;
  var iva = parseInt(valor)*valor2*1.16/100;
        
  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = 'Prima: ' + descuento.toFixed(2);
  resulta2.innerHTML = 'Total: ' + iva.toFixed(2);
  resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + iva - descuento;
}
    </script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si le quito en resultado3 'iva: ' +   si me da el resultado pero sin nombre y con decimales de mas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes corregir la siguiente línea de tu script

```
resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + iva - descuento;
```

por

```
resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + (iva - descuento);
```

Usando paréntesis ojala te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Aqui esta mejor:

```
<script>
    function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor) * valor2 / 100;
  var iva2 = parseInt(valor) * valor2 * 1.16 / 100;
  var iva = iva2 - descuento;

  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = 'Prima: ' + descuento.toFixed(2);
  resulta2.innerHTML = 'Total: ' + iva.toFixed(2);
  resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + iva;
}
    </script>
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe Asegurado</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular();" name="importe" class="form-control m-b"></div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cuota Base (%)</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor2" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular();"  name="cuota" class="form-control m-b"></div>

<span id="result" type="text" name="prima"></span><br>
<span id="resultado3" type="text" name="iva"></span><br>
<span id="resulta2" type="text" name="total"></span>
```

Lo que hice fue modificar esto:

```
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*valor2/100;
  var iva = parseInt(valor)*valor2*1.16/100;

  resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + iva - descuento;
```

Para que quede asi:

```
  var descuento = parseInt(valor) * valor2 / 100;
  var iva2 = parseInt(valor) * valor2 * 1.16 / 100;
  var iva = iva2 - descuento;

  resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + iva;
```

Tu estabas calculando el iva menos el descuento dentro de el innerHTML, esto no se debe hacer, mejor hacerlo en una variable e imprimirlo directamente, saludos :)

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias

Comment: Ahi edite mi comentario dandote una explicacion de lo que cambie, espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que hagas el calculo en otra variable.  Asi es mas facil desplegar el resultado correcto.  Quedaria asi:

```js
    function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');
  var resultado3 = document.getElementById('resultado3');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*valor2/100;
  var iva = parseInt(valor)*valor2*1.16/100;
  var t = iva - descuento;
        
  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = 'Prima: ' + descuento.toFixed(2);
  total.innerHTML = 'Total: ' + iva.toFixed(2);
  resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + t.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input id="valor" />
<input id="valor2" />
<button onClick="calcular();">Calcular</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="resultado3"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias